# Why are jqPlot axis tick text labels cropped/corrupted and axis labels not displayed?

Tags: javascript, jqplot, axis-labels

Using the latest *JQplot* version, 1.0.8, the the second graph in the example file: [AxisLabelRotatedText.html](https://github.com/lovanwubing/jqplot/blob/master/examples/axisLabelsRotatedText.html) produces the following graph:
[image: Original example from jqPlot 1.0.8 of second graph in axisLabelsRotatedText.html]

I copied the example file and made some changes to edit into what I was working on.  I was expecting to get the same graph, but ended up with a version where where the axis text is cropped:
[image: example with cropped axis text]

The following is a minimal version of the example which reproduces the error (modified from the `AxisLabelRotatedText.html` example included with the jqPlot 1.0.8 distribution):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Axis Labels and Rotated Text</title>

    <!-- Normal jQuery and jqPlot includes -->
    <link class="include" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.jqplot.min.css" /> 
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Additional plugins go here -->
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <!-- End additional plugins -->
</head>

<body dir="rtl">
    <div class="example-plot" id="chart2"></div>  
    <style type="text/css">
        .jqplot-point-label {white-space: nowrap;}
        div.jqplot-target {
            height: 400px;
            width: 750px;
            margin: 70px;
        }
    </style>
</body>

<script class="code" type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        var line2 = [['1/1/2008', 42], ['2/14/2008', 56],
                     ['3/7/2008', 39], ['4/22/2008', 81]];
        var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [line2], {
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    label: 'Incliment Occurrance',
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    tickOptions: {
                        angle: 15
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    label: 'Incliment Factor',
                    labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

The above code is assumed to be in the `examples` directory of the jqPlot 1.0.8 distribution.

Why are jqPlot axis tick text labels cropped/corrupted and axis labels not displayed with the above code?

Comment: Thanks to you for your helpful edits that led into reopening the question. I was wondering if you could post the solution as the answer, this way I can give some credit to your helps?

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you. Per your request, I have provided an answer based on your determination that right-to-left text direction was the issue (which was also how what to do to create the MCVE). As mentioned in that answer, when I went to file a jqPlot bug, I found that there was already a bug open about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [ye9ane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1888304/ye9ane) discovered, the problem is caused by setting the text direction to be right-to-left for the jqPlot `<div>`. In this instance, that is done by setting the text direction in `<body dir="rtl">`. After checking, I found that problems with right-to-left text direction is a [known bug in jqPlot](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/941/canvasaxistickrenderer-right-to-left-text).

One partial workaround is to set the text direction on just the `<div>` containing the jqPlot chart to be left-to-right while leaving the rest of the page in right-to-left. This is, obviously, imperfect in that the text in the chart will be left-to-right even if the labels are in a language which should be displayed right-to-left.

To implement the above workaround change the line:
`<div class="example-plot" id="chart2"></div>`
to
`<div class="example-plot" id="chart2" dir="ltr"></div>`

The same workaround could be implemented in CSS by using `direction: ltr;` and having it apply to an appropriate selector.